# Shield Error - "This page is trying to load unsafe scripts..." (but it's a directory issue?)

Tags: javascript, performance, ssl, pagespeed

Haven't seen something like this before. 
SSL site, loading resources from https and it's giving us a shield error. The error is due to a... 
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTgtF.png)?

Also, that js file doesn't exist in that directory, or in general.

---

Edit #1: Here's an image with more info. I've exceeded my depth on this one. The image posted below is 5 images combined; I'd post them individually, but can't post more than 2 images if I don't have enough user points — Apologies.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntIZa.jpg)

---

Solved the issue, it was a setting in W3 Cache: 
"HTTP/2 push: For better performance, send files to browser before they are requested when using the HTTP/2 protocol. 
Not supported by 'Disk: Enhanced' page cache engine."

Turns out we had "Disk: Enhanced" on, turned it off and it solved it. No idea why, but the problem is solved.

Comment: Does this file in the same website? And what about your header in HTML file?

Comment: Updated the info. Yes, it's on the same website. The red part is just blocking the domain name, it's all the same domain name under all the red marks.